# action method on block does nothing

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I've got the following block definition, which outputs the block of "my/type" just fine:

```
<block type="my/type" template="my/template.phtml">
  <action method="setMyFlag"><value>MyValue</value></action>
</block>
```

There's only one problem: setMyFlag is not invoked. I've used this approach before succesfully on other custom blocks, but for some unbeknown reason, I cannot get it to work.

I'm actually relying on the magic setters, but I've also just added the setMyFlag method to My_Type and put a breakpoint in it. All to no avail.

Any clues as to what might go wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some debugging, it seems that having a name is prerequisite for blocks to be able to invoke methods on it. So just adding a name fixes my issue:

```
<block type="my/type" template="my/template.phtml" name="my_name">
  <action method="setMyFlag"><value>MyValue</value></action>
</block>
```

Comment: In my case, merely adding the name made it work, though you need to clear the cache before reloading (xml configuration gets cached). But as Magento is a booby-trapped framework that explodes in your face whenever you cut the wrong wire, your milage may vary ;)

Comment: I have to wait 2 days before I can accept, but yeah, I will ;)

Comment: I earlier had a similar problem but have not decided. Thanks.